# How to download many elevation files to make a profile along a sizeable path in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, dem, wps, profile

I'm trying to put together [long profiles](https://apps.nationalmap.gov/services/) for rivers, which necessitates getting elevation profiles along polylines that span large distances.

I wasn't sure how to acquire the elevation data.  I don't know much about WMS and fWCS, but I tried using both from the [USGS National Map Services page](https://apps.nationalmap.gov/services/) to get imagery, which works for displaying purposes, but gives errors when trying to do profiles with the SAGA or GRASS plugins (profiles work correctly if I download a single TIFF square separately)

Is there a way to easily download the elevation files I need along a given polyline?

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: @IanTurton thanks for your input, it is appreciated, it at least gives me something to look towards, as I really have no familiarity with those topics\acronyms myself. Was there no other question on the topic or links you could provide that better explain the difference to a WFC\WCS endpoint (and where to find one for the types of data I'm looking for)? Still, something of use at least, so I can go searching, thanks.

Comment: I assume (possibly incorrectly) that anyone using a WMS also understands the other available OGC standards (WFS for vectors and WCS for rasters). Try editing your question to be shorter and more to a single question to get it reopened

Comment: @IanTurton I wasn't, no, sorry, I've used GIS on occasion, but never to the depth where I'd need such large data.  And that was the method a video suggested for getting the elevation data as I kept struggling to find the scale I needed.  Hopefully the edit is more on point, please let me know if not :-)

Comment: I'd also theoretically be up to considering lower resolution elevation data that is merged into larger files (like national level or greater), so as to be workable from a handful of file downloads, but didn't have success finding those so far.  Thanks all.

Comment: You can download ASTER Global Digital Elevation Model V003 from https://earthdata.nasa.gov/